# Is it possible to combine ng-include and other static content?

Tags: angularjs

I am just getting started working with AngularJS and have stumbled on combining multiple bits of content under the same element.  In our previous version (using knockout/durandal) we were able to leverage "container-less syntax" to make this work but it doesn't seem like we can do the same with AngularJS.

```
<ul>
   <li>this item comes from an ng-include</li>
   <li>this item is defined statically</li>
</ul>
```

What I thought would work:

```
<ul>
    <ng-include src="'thefile.html'" />
    <li>this item is defined statically</li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately, the resulting html includes an extra DOM layer wrapper which breaks my css - I am using a "ul > li" selector.

```
 <ul>
     <ng-include class="ng-scope" src="'thefile.html'">
         <li class="ng-scope">
          ...
         </li>
     </ng-include>
     <li>this item is defined statically</li>
 </ul>
```

Attempt #2 was to include the content on the  itself.  It also didn't work.  The static content was omitted completely:

```
 <ul ng-include src="'thefile.html'">
    <li>this item is defined statically</li>
 </ul>
```

Is there a smarter/correct way to do this?  I believe I'm looking for something similar to a "replace" property that I could use on a directive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `<li ng-include="'the-file.html'"></li>` not work in your setting?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  My include file has multiple <li>'s in it so I can't include it on the <li> element.

Answer (score 0):

If your css is the only thing that is causing you problems. Try

```
ul li{
        color:red;
}
```

or

```
ul > li,
ul > ng-include > li{
        color:red;
}
```